# Open a new window from an ASP.NET sub function

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET sub function that triggers on a button click via __doPostBack.
I would like to open a new window without closing the parent to perform some tricks useful to my purpose. A simple window.open (blablabla).

Is there a way to open such new window at the end of the sub function?

Comment: Please show some code that tells us what you're talking about. Also, I hope you realize that server-side code can't do client-side things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will register a startup script that will execute after the method is executed:

VB.Net Sample

```
Dim Script As String
Script = "var myWindow = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');"
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(String), "OpenerScript", Script, True)
```

c# Sample:

```
string Script = "var myWindow = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');";
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "OpenerScript", Script, true);
```

Comment: Why set `Script` to be `null` when you set it to a valid string in the next line?

Comment: I wrote the VB code and used a converter to c#. Sorry, I should have just changed it. - String Script;